# UITableView Delete, Insert & Move ordering in batch updates

Tags: uitableview

`UITableView` updates between `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` calls are batched together and all performed at the same time. [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH10-SW17) is specific about the order in which `insert` and `delete` operations are performed:

> Deletion and reloading operations within an animation block specify which rows and sections in the original table should be removed or reloaded; insertions specify which rows and sections should be added to the resulting table. The index paths used to identify sections and rows follow this model. Inserting or removing an item in a mutable array, on the other hand, may affect the array index used for the successive insertion or removal operation; for example, if you insert an item at a certain index, the indexes of all subsequent items in the array are incremented.

It's also worth noting that:

> Calls to beginUpdates and endUpdates can be nested; all indexes are treated **as if there were only the outer update block**.

[*Emphasis mine*]

So: think about deletions as occurring in a first pass, and then any insertions happening following this, using the *new* index paths that result *after* the deletions.

That's useful. **However**, I've not found any documentation about where row (and section) moves occur, which indexing they should use, and whether this impacts on the other steps. Anyone know?

Comment: I try to replace tableView.move with batch deletions and insertions because I know the order of deletions & insertions. But with no luck, move seems like something different. This made me hesitate using batch updates with FetchedResultsController because I don't know what to do with `NSFetchedResultsChangeType.move`. Do you have any progress?

Comment: No further info, sorry – you can probably test it out though?

Answer (score 7):

When moving table row, you specify two indexes:

- `indexPath` in **original table** from where to take this row
- `newIndexPath` in **resulting table** where this row will appear

  func moveRow(at indexPath: IndexPath, to newIndexPath: IndexPath)

Possible conflicting operations in single batch, causing app crash:

- trying to move a row you also deleting
- trying to move same row to multiple destinations
- trying to move several rows to the same destination
- trying to move a row to the same destination where you insert new row

It is not possible to move a row you are inserting, because it was not there in original table.

By default, moved row will be not reloaded from data source.

Comment: Hi Paiv, thank you for answering! I asked this question about two years ago and I'm not currently in a position to validate your answer! … I note that there is an open bounty that someone else has added – will you able to collect this if I have not marked your solution correct, provided they grant it to you?

Comment: To clarify – I think you are saying that we can think of moves as being like a combined delete and insert, as far as the index path is concerned? The "delete" part of the move operation occurs with other deletes (and uses the initial indexing). The insert part of the move operation happens with other inserts (and uses the post delete indexing)?

Comment: This seems the leave a remaining question of how inserts are ordered (and the insert part of moves). So, what happens if more than one row is inserted (or moved to) the same index? You mention that this would cause a crash in the case of a move. So how does one insert two rows at the start of a table, say?

Comment: In a batch, you don't see intermediate steps, and don't operate with intermediate indexes. If for example you want to insert two rows **sequentially** at the top, you would use the same index: insert(at 0), insert(at 0). But in a batch you operate with final state indexes, and declare operations that would happen in **parallel**: insert(at 0), insert(at 1), in any order.

Comment: Your confusion might come from you trying to order operations that happen in a batch. Instead think of them as happening in parallel. Your job is to declare final state, framework is responsible for proper implementation of parallel operations. The other of operations inside a batch is implementation details, and should not affect your app.

Comment: Hmm, okay, that makes some sense. But if I have existing rows [x,y] and I want to insert [a,b,c] before them in a batch, to achieve the result [a,b,c,x,y], what indexes would I use for insertion of a b and c? … would I have to move x & y to index 4 & 5?

Comment: You don't need to move existing rows, their movement is inferred from insert and delete operations. It wouldn't be an error if you move them explicitly, just unneeded work on your part. Thus to transform [x,y] into [a,b,c,x,y], you declare three insert operations in a batch: insert(a at 0), insert(b at 1), insert(c at 2).

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. It seems very weird for some reason! I'm not sure why :-) … So, basically, any existing rows are kind of squished out of the way of any inserts or moves? Or perhaps think of the inserts and moves as defining a sparse set of rows with their index paths and any original rows are then interspersed in to that to fill it out. Thank you. +1 from me, anyway.

Comment: I think it seems weird because it wasn't immediately obvious (to me, at least) that this can give an unambiguous ordering. It seems like it does though, and it seems rather neat in fact. Thanks.